# pandas stack dataframe imported from excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataaset imported from excel into a pandas dataframe. I have made a short demo example below.
This df is the result from my import.
df

```
        A   B   C  A.1  B.1  C.1  A.2  B.2  C.2
Vehicle                                          
car       4   5   5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
bike    NaN NaN NaN    3    4    5  NaN  NaN  NaN
bus     NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3    4
car       4   4   3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The column names i relabeled with a suffix in the import in to pandas. But in my Excel sheet they are the same. (only A,B,C)
What I want as a result from this is:

```
df:
         A  B  C
Vehicle         
car      4  5  5
bike     3  4  5
bus      2  3  4
car      4  4  3
```

Could someone help me with this?

I made a new dataframe for better explanation

```
     Model   A   B   C   D  A.1  B.1  C.1  D.1  A.2  B.2  C.2  D.2  A.3  B.3  \
0  34005   1   3   4   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1   1001 NaN NaN NaN NaN    3    4    5    3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
2   2003 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1    2    3    3  NaN  NaN   
3  28008 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1    2   
4  28008 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   

   C.3  D.3  A.4  B.4  C.4  D.4  
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
3    3    3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
4  NaN  NaN    1    2    3    3
```

Did not get it to work on a larger scale

```
ds_indexed

Out[350]:
       a  b  c  d  e  f  g a.1 b.1 c.1 d.1 e.1 f.1 g.1
model                                                 
30                                                    
28                           5   5   5   4   5   5   4
11                                                    
18                                                    
35                                                    
30                           5   5   5   5   5   5   3
30                           3   3   4   4   4   4   4
27                           5   5   5   4   5   5   3
34                                                    
30                                                    
2                            5   5   5   3   4   5   5
28                                                    
10                                                    
15                                                    
30                                                    
85                                                    
39                                                    
33                           5   4   4   4   3   5   3
3                            5   4   4   4   4   5   4
10                           3   3   3   2   3   4   3
3                            3   4   4   4   3   4   4
9      5  4  5  3  5  5  3

main_cols = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
new_ds = ds_indexed[main_cols]

for main_col in main_cols:
    suffix_cols = [col for col in ds_indexed.columns 
                   if col.startswith(main_col) and col != main_col]
    for suffix_col in suffix_cols:
        new_ds[main_col] = new_ds[main_col].combine_first(ds_indexed[suffix_col])


new_ds
Out[353]:
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
model                     
30                        
28                        
11                        
18                        
35                        
30                        
30                        
27                        
34                        
30                        
2                         
28                        
10                        
15                        
30                        
85                        
39                        
33                        
3                         
10                        
3                         
9      5  4  5  3  5  5  3
I can not get all the values in the new dataframe, help

ds_indexed.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 22 entries, 30.0 to 9.0
Data columns (total 14 columns):
a      22  non-null values
b      22  non-null values
c      22  non-null values
d      22  non-null values
e      22  non-null values
f      22  non-null values
g      22  non-null values
a.1    22  non-null values
b.1    22  non-null values
c.1    22  non-null values
d.1    22  non-null values
e.1    22  non-null values
f.1    22  non-null values
g.1    22  non-null values
dtypes: object(14)
```

Comment: In the last example dataframe, you would get duplicate values for certain row indices, like eg 30006. What to do with them?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing error. I have updated with a correct dataframe.

Comment: What is the difference between this dataframe and the previous? (apart from lower case column names and some more columns) Did it work on the previous dataframe?

Comment: Yes it did, this has a more missing data in it...In my larger dataframe I have over 500 columns and it has the same problem. The data under the suffix columns are not tranferred into the new dataframe...

Comment: Are you certain it are missing values? If this is the case, pandas should print 'NaN' as in your previous dataframe. Can you show the output of ``ds_indexed.info()``?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from ds_indexed.info()

Comment: As you can see in the output, you don't have missing values ('22 non-null values' while 22 rows in the dataframe). And your columns have type 'object' and not numerical. How did you import these data?

Comment: I have imported the data from excel using pd.ExcelFile

Comment: If you want help on the importing of the Excel file, you will have to show how you tried it (but maybe start a new question for it, it really is another question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby the column name via a function (e.g. the first character):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(lambda x: x[0],  axis=1).sum()
Out[11]: 
      A  B  C
car   4  5  5
bike  3  4  5
bus   2  3  4
car   4  4  3
```

Note: my previous answer worked on 0.13, where you will be able to rename the column (to only look at the first character)*:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
       A   B   C  A.1  B.1  C.1  A.2  B.2  C.2
car    4   5   5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
bike NaN NaN NaN    3    4    5  NaN  NaN  NaN
bus  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3    4
car    4   4   3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

In [22]: df.rename_axis(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)
Out[22]: 
       A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
car    4   5   5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
bike NaN NaN NaN   3   4   5 NaN NaN NaN
bus  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   2   3   4
car    4   4   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

And then groupby the column to sum:

```
In [23]: df.rename_axis(lambda x: x[0], axis=1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
Out[23]: 
      A  B  C
car   4  5  5
bike  3  4  5
bus   2  3  4
car   4  4  3
```

*In 0.12 and earlier it would not let you rename to non-unique columns, (as @joris points out) instead you can rename directly:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: I tried but ggot an error message using df.rename_axis(lambda x: x[0], axis = 1).   AssertionError: New axis must be unique to rename

Comment: @jonas ag, you're right (I was working in the development version 0.13, where this will work), that's annoying - I think it's a much neater solution.

Comment: @jonas got it, it's even easier

Comment: To rename the columns: ``df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x[0])`` like this works

Comment: @joris :) cool, I don't really understand why it was disallowed!

Comment: Ok got it, how can I move on to your groupby solution..to get to the final result

Comment: @jonas is the groupby solution output not want you want?

Comment: Yes it is, i was able to run it on this short example!! However when I tried it on the larger dataset i pasetd in today I got an error message. Could it be somthing with the excel import?? Errormessage after groupby : TypeError: ('coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found', u'occurred at index 28.0')

Comment: As I said in the comments above (below your question), you don't have numeric columns but strings and also no NaNs. This is indeed something with your import from excel.

Comment: To try this answer, you can convert your datafame to numeric with ``df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)``.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought this answer was accepted. Unclear what ds3 is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have nans in your values you can do:

```
>>> new_df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
>>> new_df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> new_df
Out[537]:
       A    B   C
Vehicle         
car    5     5   4
bike   3     4   5
bus    2     3   4
car    4     3   4
```

If this is not the case then you can use some logic on the axis names:

```
main_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
new_df = df[main_cols]

for main_col in main_cols:
    suffix_cols = [col for col in df.columns 
                   if col.startswith(main_col) and col != main_col]
    for suffix_col in suffix_cols:
        new_df[main_col] = new_df[main_col].combine_first(df[suffix_col])
```

Comment: Almost, I was not able to get rid of the suffix in my larger dataset. Any tips?

Comment: could you explain your error in more detail so that I can look into it?

Comment: Ok, i'll try. The code you sent works fine for the dataset above. But when I tried to add more variables it was not able to drop thesuffixes anymore. I cant figure out why! I made a new dataframe that explains my problem but it is to big to fit in the comments

Comment: I updated my question with the output from a new dataframe...this is the output after new_df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)

Comment: I did not get it to work on a larger frame...could you revisit and help?